# How to select the 'best' measurements out of a sample?

Tags: r, python, sample, large-data

I have about 100 water quality parameters for 300 stations, parameters were measured during different years and for each year I have different number of measurements. Not all stations measure the same number of parameters, some measure 3 or 2 parameters, while others may measure 50 or more.

The data looks something like this:

| Station | Parameter group | Parameter | Sampling year | sampling count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| station A | Sediments | Turbidity | 2010 | 12 |
| station A | Sediments | Total Suspended Solids | 2010 | 45 |
| station A | Sediments | Turbidity | 2011 | 18 |
| station A | Sediments | Total Suspended Solids | 2011 | 28 |
| station A | Nutrients | Total Phosphorus | 2010 | 2 |
| station A | Nutrients | Total Nitrogen | 2015 | 45 |
| station A | Nutrients | Total Dissolved Nitrogen | 2020 | 3 |
| station A | Nutrients | Total Dissolved Nitrogen | 2021 | 5 |
| station A | Nutrients | Free Ammonia Nitrogen | 1994 | 35 |
| station A | Heavy Metals | Arsenic - Total | 2000 | 13 |
| station A | Heavy Metals | Mercury - Total | 2011 | 53 |
| station B | Sediments | turbidity | 2011 | 21 |
| station B | Heavy Metals | Lead - Total | 2011 | 12 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |  |
| station Z | Heavy Metals | Cadmium - Total | 2019 | 142 |
| station Z | Heavy Metals | Lead - Total | 2019 | 142 |
| station Z | Heavy Metals | Arsenic - Total | 2019 | 142 |
| station Z | Heavy Metals | Cadmium - Total | 2021 | 124 |
| station Z | Heavy Metals | Lead - Total | 2021 | 124 |
| station Z | Heavy Metals | Arsenic - Total | 2021 | 124 |
| station Z | Heavy Metals | Cadmium - Total | 2020 | 124 |
| station Z | Heavy Metals | Lead - Total | 2020 | 124 |
| station Z | Heavy Metals | Arsenic - Total | 2020 | 124 |

I need to filter the number of stations by selecting the parameters that have a good number of sampling years and a good number of samples. The goal is to calculate river loads using that table information plus discharge data from other table I have. To simplify it, Load is the product of concentration of each one of the parameters presented in the table above and discharge.

The problem is that within the data in the table above there are too many stations that don't really provide much information. For example, stations that have a 20 year recorded period, but only one or two samples each year, or a station with measurements only for one year.

Basically, the need to select the "best" data is mainly for two reasons:

1. Some stations are not really useful (too few data)
2. I need to match water quality parameter stations with discharge stations to calculate loads. However, the matching has not been automated, so I have to do it manually consider some other things that are out the scope of this question.

**This is the approach I thought:**

Initially, create a column by summing up the number of samples for each parameter for all years and at the same time generate another column with the total number of years that parameter was measured. So the a second table like this one will be generated:

| Station | Parameter | Amount of samples | Amount of years samples were taken |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| station A | Turbidity | xxx | xxx |
| station A | Total Suspended Solids | xxx | xxx |
| station A | Total Nitrogen | xxx | xxx |
| station B | Turbidity | xxx | xxx |
| station B | Total Leal | xxx | xxx |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| station Z | Cadmium - Total | xxx | xxx |
| station Z | Lead - Total | xxx | xxx |
| station Z | ARsenic - Total | xxx | xxx |

From that table I would get the mean of the 'Number of samples' column and then compare that mean to each row for each parameter and discard the values below that mean. Then do the same with the 'Number of years sampled' column. This would eliminate parameters with few years or few measurements. In the end you would get the 'best' quality parameters for each station.

I don't know if there is a better approach, and as @frank pointed out, I am losing information since I did not consider each year individually. However, I was thinking that if I consider each year measured for each parameter of each station, I would not know how to determine the best parameters. if for one year the data are "bad" but for other years the data are good, I would still consider that parameter for that station to be good, regardless of that one "bad" year.

Maybe I can also use a weighted average as mentioned by @Tim, I will need to think how to implement it.

I would appreciate any thoughts and ideas.

Comment: It would be very helpful to know what the data is used for and how. You presume that number of samples and number of years are measures of quality, but on what grounds? E.g., I could imagine that number of samples per year might be another/better criterion, or you might want to consider the variance of the data, many possibilities exist. It is really difficult to know without more information about how the data is used.

Comment: Why do you need to pick a single "best" one rather than use the available data to estimate the true parameter value? In the simplest case, this would be a weighted average with weights proportionate to the number of datapoints.

Comment: @frank. Thanks for your support. I have given more information.

Comment: @Tim I tried to answered why I need to select the 'best' parameters. I hope this information is useful.

Comment: Having just completed a project that sounds identical to this one, I can attest that modeling the parameters explicitly using splines of river mile and time can be an effective way to use *all* your data and thereby make your estimates more accurate and precise.  Every station is potentially useful (unless you mistrust its data quality).  To deal with the inevitable data quality issues--general parameters like turbidity and TSS have notoriously large sampling errors--I fit the models using IRLS ("robust regression") rather than OLS.

Comment: @whuber your idea of using splines to all the data sounds interesting. Unfortunately, a method to match concentration and discharge stations has not been implemented. I have different discharge stations that could potentially be used along with the different concentration stations. There is still a lot of debate to really decide under what conditions a discharge station is representative for a certain concentration station. For now, I only need to present a preliminary analysis of the stations with the "best" parameters, that's why I decided to ask this question here and look for some ideas.